# Is there a way to enforce one of many files in Apache Maven Enforcer rule "Require Files Exist"?

Tags: java, maven, maven-enforcer-plugin

I am using the rule [requireFilesExists](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireFilesExist.html) of the Maven Enforcer Plugin. I need to enforce a README-file. This can be for example a file called README.adoc or README.md. The documentation only says that a list of files can be provided which are all enforced. But I see no way to enforce a list where only one file would be sufficient.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can combine rules with boolean logic...so i guess either the [beanshell rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/evaluateBeanshell.html) or a [custom rule](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html) remain as the options? Or maybe someone already made a custom rule like this?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few standard rules like: [`requireFiles...`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html) all rules extends class: [AbstractRequireFiles](https://github.com/apache/maven-enforcer/blob/master/enforcer-rules/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/enforcer/AbstractRequireFiles.java).

All files given as list must satisfy rule.

You can add next parameter to `AbstractRequireFiles`, eg `satisfyAny`.
Implementation should not be difficult.

Issue for track [MENFORCER-430](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-430) and for fix for volunteers :-)